# PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR: column "encrypted_password" of relation "users" already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise, migration

So I've ran into a problem with running rails db:migrate which gives this error:

```
== 20190301194540 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "encrypted_password" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "encrypted_password" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:75:in `async_exec'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:74:in `block in execute'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:73:in `execute'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:581:in `add_column'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:420:in `add_column'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:527:in `column'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:232:in `block in string'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:232:in `each'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:232:in `string'
/Users/programming/Desktop/fitnesshabbits/db/migrate/20190301194540_add_devise_to_users.rb:8:in `block in up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:471:in `change_table'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:871:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in `say_with_time'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:860:in `method_missing'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:604:in `method_missing'
/Users/programming/Desktop/fitnesshabbits/db/migrate/20190301194540_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:817:in `exec_migration'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:797:in `block in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `with_connection'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:796:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:977:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1292:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1343:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `block in transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1343:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1291:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1263:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `each'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `block in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1363:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/programming/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/programming/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "encrypted_password" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "encrypted_password" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:75:in `async_exec'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:74:in `block in execute'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:73:in `execute'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:581:in `add_column'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:420:in `add_column'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:527:in `column'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:232:in `block in string'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:232:in `each'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:232:in `string'
/Users/programming/Desktop/fitnesshabbits/db/migrate/20190301194540_add_devise_to_users.rb:8:in `block in up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:471:in `change_table'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:871:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in `say_with_time'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:860:in `method_missing'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:604:in `method_missing'
/Users/programming/Desktop/fitnesshabbits/db/migrate/20190301194540_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:817:in `exec_migration'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:797:in `block in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `with_connection'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:796:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:977:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1292:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1343:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `block in transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1343:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1291:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1263:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `each'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `block in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1363:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/programming/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/programming/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
/Users/programming/Desktop/fitnesshabbits/db/migrate/20190301194540_add_devise_to_users.rb:8:in `block in up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:471:in `change_table'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:871:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:840:in `say_with_time'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:860:in `method_missing'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:604:in `method_missing'
/Users/programming/Desktop/fitnesshabbits/db/migrate/20190301194540_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:817:in `exec_migration'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:797:in `block in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `with_connection'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:796:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:977:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1292:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1343:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `block in transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1343:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1291:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1263:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `each'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `block in migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1363:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/programming/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/programming/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/programming/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This problem occurs even if I drop the database, comment out specific fields like, for example, encrypted_password in migration file. I've also tried to reset migration, set it to development mode. I'm using Devise and trying to run this migration file. If anyone got any ideas of why or how this happens I'd appreciate some ideas to fix this issue.

Could this happen because of an error in a certain file?

Migration status:

```
database: fitnesshabbits_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20190227233216  Devise create users
  down    20190301194540  Add devise to users
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a new column to the devise users migration?

Comment: `encrypted_password` already exists in `schema.rb` ?

Comment: **Where is the code?**

Comment: No actually not I was just trying to run db:migrate for the first time. Maybe doing a hard reset back and then redoing my changes are a good idea beside resetting db.

Comment: If you have just only 1 migration file would you share it? If not then would you run `db:migrate:status` and share the output?

Comment: Fortunately I have a repo for it. When I’m home I’ll commit the latest changes and then I’ll share the link to it. That should work properly. It’s a newly started project so not much code.

Comment: I've included migration status in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have add the same field in your two migrations. 
I think that you `have add encrypted_password in you AddDeviseToUsers migration`. 
Lock that in your migrations don't have field that are repeat.